# Transform mouse listener coordinates into chart coordinates

Tags: java, jfreechart, mouselistener

I want to set dots in my app with mouse click. I use JFreeChart and use in ChartPanel mouse listener. This is look like this:

```
panel.addChartMouseListener(new ThisMouseListener());
```

and my mouse listener ThisMouseListener() (it is not finished):

```
class ThisMouseListener implements ChartMouseListener{

    @Override
    public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent event) {
        int x = event.getTrigger().getX();
        int y = event.getTrigger().getY();

        System.out.println("X :" + x + " Y : " + y);

        ChartEntity entity = event.getEntity();
        if(entity != null && (entity instanceof XYItemEntity)){
            XYItemEntity item = (XYItemEntity)entity;
        }
        new JOptionPane().showMessageDialog(null, "Hello", "Mouse Clicked event", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
    }

    @Override
    public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

but this mouse listener returns me my panel coordinates and I want to get coordinates from my chart. May be I must use listener with other object? or I can transform coordinates with some method?

Comment: Do you want to _add_ new points or _select_ existing ones? Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your current approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You added the listener to the panel. Therefore when you click the mouse you receive coordinates relative to the panel - which is the source of the event. You need to add this listener to the chart instead.

Other possibility is to get coordinates of the chart in respect to panel and subtract them from x and y.

```
Point p = chart.getLocation();     
int px = p.getX();
int py = p.getY();

x = x-px; // x from event
y = y-py; // y from event
// x and y are now coordinates in respect to the chart

if(x<0 || y<0 || x>chart.getWidth() || y>chart.getHeight()) // the click was outside of the chart
else // the click happened within boundaries of the chart and
```

If the panel is the container of the chart component your solution might look something like the above one. Note that these coordinates will be coordinates in respect to left top corner of the chart.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a little brittle? It seems like you'd have to work inside the renderer to get reliable geometry.

Comment: what do you mean by brittle? Do you think it could crash at some point? By the renderer do you mean the chartMouseClicked() function in the listener(i think you mean this-http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/render/Renderer.html)? I omitted the declaration of x and y not because I suggest to include it inside the mouse clicked function, but to note the source of those variables.

Comment: I meant brittle in the sense that chart-relative coordinates may change, while the renderer can use the axis to convert between screen and model coordinates.

Comment: JFreeChart has not such method chart.getLocation();

Answer (score 2):

Get the x,y coordinates in your graph space via

```
double x = event.getChart().getXYPlot().getDomainCrosshairValue();
double y = event.getChart().getXYPlot().getRangeCrosshairValue();
```

One major PROBLEM:  I find that JFreeChart doesn't update these values until *after* my ChartMouseEvent handler is called; each time through I get the previous values.   You can look at XYPlot.handleClick(x,y,info) for details to get the current values in your handler.

Answer (score 1):

You have to obtain a reference to the ChartPanel, rredraw it and only after that you can get a correct X,Y coordinates from the Plot. To do so, you have to place coordinate retrieval on the awt queue and not call it directly. Below is an example that worked for me (for X coordinate only)

```
@Override
public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent cme) {
    final ChartMouseEvent cmeLocal = cme;
    ChartPanel hostChartPanel = (ChartPanel) cme.getTrigger().getComponent();
    if (null != hostChartPanel) {

        //Crosshair values are not valid until after the chart has been updated
        //that is why call repaint() now and post Crosshair value retrieval on the
        //awt thread queue to get them when repaint() is finished
        hostChartPanel.repaint();

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFreeChart chart = cmeLocal.getChart();
                XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
                double crossHairX = plot.getDomainCrosshairValue();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Double.toString(crossHairX), "X-Value", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
            }
        });
    }
}
```